# UTF8 error in shapado installation

Tags: shapado

Hi I did the installation until “rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development” line. After that I get this error

WARNING: Sinatra 1.2.x has reached its EOL. Please upgrade. rake aborted! (eval):1: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (eval):1: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-�-�]{0,24}/

```
                 ^
```

/home/canercak/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/mongoidext-ea4337c5aebe/lib/mongoidext.rb:8:in '
/home/canercak/dev/shapado/config/application.rb:16:in‘ /home/canercak/dev/shapado/Rakefile:4:in `’ (See full trace by running task with —trace)

I have ubuntu 13 runnig in US-EN settings. I used magic_encoding to add “# –– encoding : utf-8 ––” on top of every file but still get the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out by changing rvm version to 1.9ç.3 and reinstalling the app